# What are the additive/multiplicative identities and the additive inverse in the vector space F[a,b]?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To be specific, F[a,b] is a vector space of functions defined in [a,b] with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. My problem is that I can't well understand or comprehend those things that I listed in the title. For example, What exactly does the **0** vector mean when it has something to do with functions.

In addition, I can't well explain or prove that the functions in [a,b] with pointwise addition and multiplication is closed under two operations.

Comment: No, I meant all functions in [a,b].

Comment: The **0** vector would be the constant function zero.

Comment: @EA304GT How about the other one? Could you help me prove that it's closed under both operations?

Comment: Take for example $h=f+g$. Then $h$ is a function in $[a,b]$ since $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. Same goes for $h=cf$.

Comment: @EA304GT That's just where my problem is. Why does f(x) and g(x) in [a,b] imply f(x)+g(x) in [a,b]?